# Tensorflow cost not updating

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am working through Andrew Ng's ML course on Coursera, and have recently had the opportunity to apply tensorflow to a real world environment, at which point things promptly fell over :D.

My code below works insofar as it doesn't produce any bugs... but neither does the cost change. From what I have read, and from what I understand, this is because the gradients are all zero. The thing is, I don't understand why this is and how to fix it...

The problem I am working on is a regression model implemented as a shallow neural net with 1 hidden layer of 10 units, to estimate daily sales across a large portfolio of properties.

So, code:

```
def create_placeholders():

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [13, None], name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None], name="Y")

return X, Y

# Initialise weights and biases. Hidden layer of 10, output layer of 1
def initialise_parameters():
    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [10, 13], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=1))
    b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", [10, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", [1, 10], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=1))
    b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", [1, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    parameters = {"W1": W1, "b1": b1, "W2": W2, "b2": b2}

    return parameters

def forward_propagation(X, parameters):

    # Retrieve the parameters from the dictionary "parameters"
    W1 = parameters['W1']
    b1 = parameters['b1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    b2 = parameters['b2']

    Z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W1, X), b1)
    A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)
    Z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W2, A1), b2)
    A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)
    # Have a relu output because a) why not, and b) its sales data so negatives are nonsense.
    return A2


# COST FUNCTION
def compute_cost(y_hat, y):
    # Originally tried reduce_mean but gave same outcome of constant cost
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_hat - y))

    return cost

# CHECK DIMENSIONS ARE ALL GOOD
[x.shape for x in [X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test]]
Out[48]: [(13, 331768), (1, 331768), (13, 41471), (1, 41471)]

# W1 shape = (10, 13), W1*X = (10,13) * (13, m) = (10, m)
# W2 shape = (1, 10),  W2 * (W1*X) = (1,10) * (10, m) = (1,m)
# good

# X's have all been normalised using sklean.preprocessing.StandardScaler()

learning_rate = 0.0001
tf.reset_default_graph()

costs = []  # To keep track of the cost
X, Y = create_placeholders()

# Initialize parameters
parameters = initialise_parameters()

y_hat = forward_propagation(X, parameters)

cost = compute_cost(y_hat, Y)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
# Alternative
# optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Run the initialization
    sess.run(init)

    # Do the training loop
    # Range is small here but have done up to 2000 and get same result.
    for epoch in range(10):
        _, epoch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})
        print(epoch_cost)

Output:
8.932417e+17
9.986363e+32
8.9324173e+17
8.9324173e+17
8.9324173e+17
8.9324173e+17
8.9324173e+17
8.9324173e+17
8.9324173e+17
8.9324173e+17
```

Where am I going wrong with this? What is causing the gradient to be zero?
Thanks

Sample data:

```
pd.DataFrame(X_train).iloc[:, :3]
Out[38]: 
           0         1         2
0  -2.639472  1.567537  0.000027
1   0.611774  0.377617 -0.317175
2   0.228070  0.095461  0.129151
3   0.098627  0.924450 -1.553019
4   0.428524  1.053880 -0.661481
5  -0.068319  1.084136  2.015653
6   0.788444  0.882707 -0.555907
7   0.450732  1.168514 -0.576461
8   0.438508 -0.281488 -0.338060
9   0.241477 -0.014153 -0.582811
10  0.248324  0.020088 -0.174162
11  0.007352 -1.261135  1.666470
12  0.134369  0.191141  0.235396

pd.DataFrame(y_train).iloc[:, :3]
Out[43]: 
               0             1             2
0  279637.377287  2.796952e+06  57194.231303
```

Row means (rows = features, columns = observations) are zero

```
pd.DataFrame(X_train).mean(axis=1)
Out[41]: 
0     5.572480e-12
1     2.818636e-14
2    -3.316111e-17
3    -2.587781e-12
4     3.080923e-13
5     1.078905e-13
6    -4.661424e-15
7     1.534782e-13
8    -9.438911e-13
9     2.328588e-14
10   -2.219427e-14
11   -9.047083e-15
```

Comment: FWIW, you should probably initialize your biases a bit more randomly (not exactly all at zero).

Comment: The high cost implies that the inputs are not normalized.

Comment: Biases usually are initialized at 0. Otherwise, your network would start with a "bias" towards some cases, and it's not what you want

Comment: Please show us a sample of the data you are using

Comment: Hi, 
Costs are normalised through sklearn StandardScaler. Have added sample data. Thanks!

Comment: OK, 
So, I know this is a data issue now - running the same code on the boston housing data worked as expected. Good to find that out!